# Exception after update to Entity Framework 6.1.1 from 6.1.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use code first and have a structure of classes. I have `EntityDO` class, that describe all entities. `MetadataEntityDO` - metadata description class. And lot of classes that inherit from `MetadataEntityDO` (`AreaTemplateDO` for example)

```
public abstract class EntityDO
{
 //...
}

public abstract class MetadataEntityDO : EntityDO
{
 //...
}

public class AreaTemplateDO : MetadataEntityDO
{
 //...
}
```

Mapping configuration in `DbContext`:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<MetadataEntityDO>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("MetadataEntity");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AreaTemplateDO>().Map(m => m.ToTable("AreaTemplate"));
    }
```

I send some data into the database

```
    [Test]
    public void PAGiTMetadataContext_AddEntity_ChangeUpdateDateTime()
    {
        Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();

        using (var dc = new PAGiTMetadataContext(testTimemanager, "TestEntityDatabase"))
        {
            dc.AreaTemplates.Add(new AreaTemplateDO() { ID = guid, Name = "Name", VersionCount = 1 });
            dc.SaveChanges();
            areaTemplate = dc.AreaTemplates.First(p => p.ID == guid);
        }
    }
```

In EF 6.1.0 it works fine, but after update to 6.1.1 I get this exception:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException : Error retrieving values from ObjectStateEntry. See inner exception for details.
>   ----> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException : Error retrieving values from ObjectStateEntry. See inner exception for details.
>   ----> System.Data.Entity.Core.MappingException :
>   (265,10) : error 3032: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 265, 399:EntityTypes PAG.PAGiT.Data.AreaTemplateDO, PAG.PAGiT.Data.TemplateadditionlaAttributeDO, PAG.PAGiT.Data.BasicUnitDO, PAG.PAGiT.Data.TemplateConstraintDO, PAG.PAGiT.Data.TemplateScriptDO, PAG.PAGiT.Data.CatalogTemplateDO, PAG.PAGiT.Data.ConstantTemplateDO, PAG.PAGiT.Data.MaterialTemplateDO, PAG.PAGiT.Data.BasicOperationInOutTemplateDO, PAG.PAGiT.Data.BasicOperationTemplateDO, PAG.PAGiT.Data.OperationTemplateDO, PAG.PAGiT.Data.PlantTemplateDO, PAG.PAGiT.Data.ProcessUnitTemplateDO, PAG.PAGiT.Data.RecipeElementDO, PAG.PAGiT.Data.RecipeElementInOutDO, PAG.PAGiT.Data.RecipeProcedureDO, PAG.PAGiT.Data.RecipeProcedureFormulaDO, PAG.PAGiT.Data.StringListDO, PAG.PAGiT.Data.UserTemplateDO, PAG.PAGiT.Data.WorkOrderTemplateDO are being mapped to the same rows in table MetadataEntityDO. Mapping conditions can be used to distinguish the rows that these types are mapped to.
>
> Result StackTrace:
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
>   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
>   at PAG.PAGiT.Data.PAGiTMetadataContext.SaveChanges() в c:\WorkGitRep\PAG.PAGiT\PAG.PAGiT.Data\PAGiTMetadataContext.cs:строка 84
>   at  PAG.PAGiT.Data.IntegrationTest.PAGiTMetadataContextTest.PAGiTMetadataContext_AddEntity_ChangeUpdateDateTime()
>   at c:\WorkGitRep\PAG.PAGiT\PAG.PAGiT.Data.IntegrationTest\PAGiTMetadataContextTest.cs:строка 52
>
> UpdateException
>
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.RecordConverter.ConvertStateEntryToPropagatorResult(IEntityStateEntry stateEntry, Boolean useCurrentValues, ModifiedPropertiesBehavior modifiedPropertiesBehavior)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.ExtractedStateEntry..ctor(UpdateTranslator translator, IEntityStateEntry stateEntry)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.LoadStateEntry(IEntityStateEntry stateEntry)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.PullModifiedEntriesFromStateManager()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.ProduceCommands()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.b__2(UpdateTranslator ut)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update()
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__35()
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.b__27()
>   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>
>       в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
>       в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
>       в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
>       --MappingException
>       в System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.ViewDictionary.SerializedGenerateViews(EntityContainerMapping entityContainerMap, Dictionary`2 resultDictionary)
>       в System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.ViewDictionary.SerializedGetGeneratedViews(EntityContainer container)
>       в System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Evaluate>b__0()
>       в System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Result.GetValue()
>       в System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Evaluate(TArg arg)
>       в System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.ViewDictionary.GetGeneratedView(EntitySetBase extent, MetadataWorkspace workspace, StorageMappingItemCollection storageMappingItemCollection)
>       в System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.ViewLoader.InitializeEntitySet(EntitySetBase entitySetBase, MetadataWorkspace workspace)
>       в System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.ViewLoader.SyncInitializeEntitySet[TArg,TResult](EntitySetBase entitySetBase, MetadataWorkspace workspace, Func`2 evaluate, TArg arg)
>       в System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.ExtractorMetadata..ctor(EntitySetBase entitySetBase, StructuralType type, UpdateTranslator translator)
>       в System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.GetExtractorMetadata(EntitySetBase entitySetBase, StructuralType type)
>       в System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.ExtractorMetadata.ExtractResultFromRecord(IEntityStateEntry stateEntry, Boolean isModified, IExtendedDataRecord record, Boolean useCurrentValues, UpdateTranslator translator, ModifiedPropertiesBehavior modifiedPropertiesBehavior)
>       в System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.RecordConverter.ConvertStateEntryToPropagatorResult(IEntityStateEntry stateEntry, Boolean useCurrentValues, ModifiedPropertiesBehavior modifiedPropertiesBehavior)

Is anybody know how to fix?

Comment: What is the inner exception?

Comment: InnerException: System.Data.Entity.Core.MappingException
            HResult=-2146232032
            Message=
(265,10) : error 3032: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 265, 399:EntityTypes PAG.PAGiT.Data.AreaTemplateDO, PAG.PAGiT.Data.TemplateadditionlaAttributeDO, PAG.PAGiT.Data.BasicUnitDO, .../*lot of my classes*/ are being mapped to the same rows in table MetadataEntityDO. Mapping conditions can be used to distinguish the rows that these types are mapped to.